# How to check if the given name exists in firebase realtime database in android studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to check that if the given name exists in "FacultyMember" record. 
If the given name is found in the record then I want to retrieve its parent (that is uid) other show a message name not found. How can I do it in the android studio?
This is my database structure.
Thanks

[[image: This is my database Structure.]

Comment: If you want to know if something exists in Realtime Database, you have to query for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do in this case is, order your database concerned child with `Name` and compare them to the `nameYouWant`, and using `dataSnapshot.exists()` decide what you have to do with the user.

What I am saying, looks something like this in code:

```java
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("FacultyMember");
databaseReference.orderByChild("Name").equalTo(nameYouWant).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
          for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
               String uid = childSnapshot.getKey();
        }
        else
            // no such user exists

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { // ToDo: Do something for errors too

    }
});
```

Comment: In this code, in uid its return "FacultyMember" but i want to get unique id(its parent)

Comment: @AbbasAli ah, my bad! please try the updated code.